# Using a Media Session to capture from microphone produces wrong timestamps

Tags: sharpdx, ms-media-foundation

In my setup I use the following API calls:

- *MFEnumDeviceSources* to get a media source for the microphone
- *MFTranscodeGetAudioOutputAvailableTypes* with *MFAudioFormat_AAC* to get a compatible AAC media type
- *MFCreateTranscodeProfile* and *MFCreateTranscodeTopologyFromByteStream* to get a topology to capture live audio from the microphone into a memory buffer

After I run the media session, the buffer can be played back but the duration of the media is not correct. Inserting a tee node and a sample grabber shows that the live media source is providing sample times close to the system time and those are the sample times that arrive into the sink.

I have tried setting *MF_TOPONODE_MARKIN_HERE* and *MF_TOPONODE_MARKOUT_HERE* on all three nodes of the topology, without success. I also checked, and none of the nodes have it set by default (although the topology will be modified by the topology loader and I did not try to check that step).

I know I could create a custom transform and manipulate the sample times there (although I am not 100% sure how), but since my code is in C#, I am trying to keep custom code out of the main pipeline.

Can someone give me some ideas how to force the session to present the right sample times to the sink?

Comment: Did you also check the value of MFSampleExtension_DeviceTimestamp attribute on the samples?

Comment: No, I didn't. I expect it would be the same as the sample time in this case, no? I think that is the whole problem that I have, that I'm getting the device time as sample time from the source.

BTW, I will check it when I get time.

Comment: You can see if it is different. Also check this out: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee318414(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link, it does look interesting. The two choices don't look too encouraging (system time vs hardware time) but there is hope that the media session will be able to adjust to one of them and produce timestamps starting from the beginning of the recording.

Comment: Another option would be to use imfsourcereader instead of media session and topology. This way you will manipulate the timestamps after each readsample.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that... I could also use a transform node to do that in the topology. I loved the solution with the media session because that way I could keep the processing in the native code, which presumably has better performance. On the other hand, I might be too cautious, and it might be just fine running it through .NET code.

Comment: Indeed native code will perform better. You can always create a managed c++ assembly and put all the media foundation stuff in it.